# Bash script to obtain forwarding port and insert into config file for program

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I've written some bash scripts, but this is just beyond me and I have no idea where to start. I'm running Xubuntu.  I'm using a VPN that allows me to have a forwarded port forwarded, but only by running the following line, which produces the output below, with a different port each time.

```
Command:
./port_forward.sh user password
Output:
Loading port forward assignment information..
{"port:58661}
```

I'm looking to make a script that runs that process, takes the port output, and then puts it into the configuration file for Deluge, and then runs Deluge. I've pasted my current configuration below, the two instances of 32157 would need to be changed to the new port. This file is located at /home/user/.config/deluge/core.conf

```
{
"file": 1,
"format": 1
}{
"info_sent": 0.0,
"lsd": true,
"send_info": false,
"move_completed_path": "/media/sf_Storage2/Download folder",
"enc_in_policy": 1,
"queue_new_to_top": false,
"ignore_limits_on_local_network": true,
"rate_limit_ip_overhead": true,
"daemon_port": 58846,
"natpmp": true,
"max_active_limit": 8,
"utpex": true,
"max_active_downloading": 5,
"max_active_seeding": 0,
"allow_remote": false,
"max_half_open_connections": 50,
"download_location": "/media/sf_Storage2/Temp Download Folder",
"compact_allocation": false,
"max_upload_speed": -1.0,
"cache_expiry": 60,
"prioritize_first_last_pieces": false,
"auto_managed": true,
"enc_level": 2,
"max_connections_per_second": 20,
"dont_count_slow_torrents": true,
"random_outgoing_ports": true,
"max_upload_slots_per_torrent": -1,
"new_release_check": false,
"enc_out_policy": 1,
"outgoing_ports": [
0,
0
],
"seed_time_limit": 180,
"cache_size": 512,
"share_ratio_limit": 2.0,
"max_download_speed": -1.0,
"geoip_db_location": "/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat",
"torrentfiles_location": "/home/user/Downloads",
"stop_seed_at_ratio": false,
"peer_tos": "0x00",
"listen_interface": "",
"upnp": true,
"max_download_speed_per_torrent": -1,
"max_upload_slots_global": 4,
"enabled_plugins": [],
"random_port": false,
"autoadd_enable": false,
"max_connections_global": 200,
"enc_prefer_rc4": true,
"listen_ports": [
32157,
32157
],
"dht": true,
"stop_seed_ratio": 2.0,
"seed_time_ratio_limit": 7.0,
"max_upload_speed_per_torrent": -1,
"copy_torrent_file": false,
"del_copy_torrent_file": false,
"move_completed": true,
"proxies": {
"peer": {
"username": "",
"password": "",
"type": 0,
"hostname": "",
"port": 8080
},
"web_seed": {
"username": "",
"password": "",
"type": 0,
"hostname": "",
"port": 8080
},
"tracker": {
"username": "",
"password": "",
"type": 0,
"hostname": "",
"port": 8080
},
"dht": {
"username": "",
"password": "",
"type": 0,
"hostname": "",
"port": 8080
}
},
"add_paused": false,
"max_connections_per_torrent": -1,
"remove_seed_at_ratio": false,
"autoadd_location": "/home/user/Downloads",
"plugins_location": "/home/user/.config/deluge/plugins"
}
```

Is this possible? If there's a way to use the output from the command, I would think I could store a given port number in a seperate file that would then be used by the script to find the and replace with the new port number, and then change the number in the file for the next run.

ETA:

Thanks! I wasn't quite sure how you meant I'd get the new port, so I came up with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
OLDPORT=`cat core.conf | grep -A2 listen_ports | tail -n1`
A=$(~/port_forward.sh user password)
B=$(echo -e "$A" | sed -n '2p')
PORT=`echo $B| cut -c9-13`
sed -i 's/'$OLDPORT'/'$PORT'/g' "core.conf"
deluge-gtk %U
```

It works, though I'm certain there are cleaner ways to do it. I would be interested if there's a way to simply take whatever 5 digit number is contained in the output of the port_forward.sh command and make it a variable. Obviously what I have above is not ideal and will break if the output is changed at all.  And yes, it does have just the one double quote, no idea why.

ETA2: Never mind, I figured it out.  Thanks again for your help!

```
#!/bin/bash
OLDPORT=`cat core.conf | grep -A2 listen_ports | tail -n1`
PORT=$(~/port_forward.sh user password| grep -o "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")
sed -i 's/'$OLDPORT'/'$PORT'/g' "core.conf"
deluge-gtk %U
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clean it up a bit by using **parameter expansion/substring extraction**. Give the following a try. It eliminates numerous 3rd party app calls along with the subshells they spawn. I don't have your `port_forward.sh` script to test the exact output, but the following should work based on what you have posted:

```
#!/bin/bash
OLDPORT=`grep -A2 listen_ports core.conf | tail -n1`
A=$(~/port_forward.sh user password)
tmp=${A##*port:}
PORT=${tmp%\}*}
sed -i 's/'$OLDPORT'/'$PORT'/g' "core.conf"
deluge-gtk %U
```

**Note** how I rearranged your `OLDPORT` line. Try and avoid all **UUoC** (Unnecessary Use of `cat`). If you ever find yourself doing `cat something |`, that should tell you there is a more appropriate way to do it. Usually by giving the filename directly, using **redirection**, or by use of a **herestring**, or by redirecting the output of a subshell... It just takes practice.

Comment: That does look like a better way to get oldport, but I think the way I figured out how to do the new port that I added to my question is cleaner and makes more sense.

Comment: Yep, using character classes is a smart way to approach it. Glad you are happy with that solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use sed to change the old port number to the new one, for example.

```
sed 's/32157/58661/g' core.conf > core.new
mv core.new core.conf
```

The sed will change the old port number to the new one and redirect the output to a new file named core.new and then the mv will overwrite the old file with the new one.

You can do it in a script too, you just need to set the old port and the new port as variables.

To get the old port as a variable you could do something like that.

```
oldport=`cat core.conf | grep -A2 listen_ports | tail -n1`
```

This will cat the core.conf file, look for the listen_ports string and print it and the two lines after and the tail will get the last line, which will be the port number, of course, considering that will always be two port numbers.

To get the new port you could pass it as the first parameter of the script, so you would have something like that.

```
#!/bin/bash
oldport=`cat core.conf | grep -A2 listen_ports | tail -n1`
sed 's/$1/$oldport/g' core.conf > core.new
mv core.new core.conf
```

The output of that port_forward.sh is right? It looks like it's missing a double quote. Shouldn't it be something like that.

```
{"port:58661"}
```

You also can get the port value from this output using awk.

Comment: Thanks! Just added some more details to my question.  One more thing I could use help on.